# Why can't I print a random integer numpy array with range()

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to print a 2-D random integer numpy array but I'm getting an error.

```py
import numpy as np

a=np.random.randint(100,size=(2,4))

for i in range(a):

    print(i)
```

The error message says:

> "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: If you want to print `a`, why not do `print(a)`? `range` function only accepts integers as input.

Comment: Post the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer which does not use range is totally fine.

In case you need the current index (i) or keep range for some reason;

```
for i in range(len(a)): 
    print(a[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

`range(a)` produces a `range` object of the integers `0, 1, ..., a-1` if 'a' is numeric.

If 'a' is a numpy array and you want to iterate through its values, use:

```
for i in a:
   print(i)
```